# How to clear a session variable which includes a list in C#?

Tags: c#, session-variables

I have a class as following:

```
public class Employee 
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<int> ProjectIDs { get; set; } 
}
```

and at one point I stored a List to session variable, like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
// populate employees

Session["EmployeeList"] = employees;
```

When I'm done using it, I want to clear it, so I do:

```
Session["EmployeeList"] = null;
```

EmployeeID and Name is to clear out, but not the `List<int> ProjectIDs` that's in it. How to make sure `Session["EmployeeList"]` is cleared out completely?

Comment: You don't need to.  The garbage collector knows how to do its job.

Comment: @SLaks fixed a spelling error in my question. I meant to point out that the `List<int>` in the session variable wasn't cleared out when I tested it, while `EmployeeID` and `Name` are both cleared out.

Comment: Are you saying that you assigned `null` to `Session["EmployeeList"]` and subsequently you can still retrieve a valid list from `Session["EmployeeList"]`?? That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Remove()` method on `Session` object saying

```
Session.Remove("EmployeeList");
```

BTW, what you say shouldn't be; once you set the session object to null saying `Session["EmployeeList"] = null;` ... then trying to get back the same session object with that key `((List<Employee>)Session["EmployeeList"]) == null ;` should return null

Comment: You're right, turns out the code was setting it back somewhere else it got saved to session. Thanks!